# remove space button from rgbdslam

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to place kinect and laptop on the irobot create . what i want to do is removing the space/enter button from rgbdslam. If i,m not wrong rgbdslam require space button to be pressed. how to remove it ? .
thankyou

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65233/remove-space-button-from-rgbdslam/) by [Xittx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4233/xittx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unsure of what you want. I guess you want it to start by itself, not wait until a button is pressed. In that case set the parameter "start_paused" to "false" in your launch file:

```
<param name="config/start_paused"                  value="false"/>
```

or use `rosparam set /rgbdslam/config/start_paused false` prior to starting rgbdslam.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0